# How is Kamala Khan's name pronounced?

Tags: marvel, comics, pronunciation, ms-marvel

[Kamala Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms._Marvel_(Kamala_Khan)) is the current Ms. Marvel. How is her name pronounced? I assume that her last name is pronounced [the same way that Shatner says it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EnsUeR2MyI), but what about her first name? Camel-a? Cam-ah-la? Cay-mala?

Ideally, I'd love to hear the creators of the series say her name on video, but if there are non-video sources from Marvel that explain her name's pronunciation, that would be fine too.

Comment: Just as a minor trivia, the character is X-American so there'll likely be some Americanisation of the name either through the character or creators themselves, but if she had retained the accent relative to her origin (as many X-Americans do when speaking in their language of origin), it'd be more "Come-uh-la" and less "Come-ah-la"

Comment: I believe it's "Mah-_vell_"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The co-creator of the new Ms. Marvel (**Sana Amanat**) says her name in this interview. It's as you would expect it to be pronounced; *Ca-mah-laa*

The character's other co-creator (**G. Willow Wilson**) pronounces it in a very similar fashion.

Comment: I could add another couple of interviews, but it's basically the same pronunciation again and again from both women. Do you want me to do overkill or just leave it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y1ihwPplL4&feature=youtu.be&t=11m51s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVQWhRxU2mI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m47s

Comment: @Thunderforge Many of the subcontinent languages don't use an explicit syllable/vowel between certain syllables unless they intend to add a deep emphasis. The transition from one to the next can be very short as a result. Sort of like an apostrophe.

Comment: @DariM - Also she's talking quickly and has done 40 other interviews that day.

Comment: The videos you have are fine. It just sounded like two syllables instead of three to me.

Comment: @Valorum Yep. And fluency with a name accentuates it differently, same like in French where vowels/words mix together when you speak fast/fluently. Writing Kamala in Hindi or Tamil would basically be equivalent to "K-M-L-ah"

Comment: @Thunderforge - I'm no linguist. I wrote it down foe-net-ick-al-ee so that it made sense to me. I'm sure if you wandered over to [Linguistics:SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) they'd tell you what it actually looks like in proper annotation.

Comment: That second video is brilliant :)

Answer (score -1):

The Vice President’s name is pronounced Comma-la, and is of Sanskrit origin. Ms. Marvel’s name is of Arabic origin and pronounced Kuh-maa-luh. Feminine version of the word Kamal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include some supporting evidence, such as a source of some kind.

Comment: I'm not sure what the VPs name has anything to do with how this character's name is pronounced.

Comment: Vice President of where?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - One of the colonies, I expect. They're forever changing Head of State. It's really quite hard to keep up.